# Filebeat 6.2 cannot parse json logs of docker container

Tags: json, docker, filebeat

My application logs in json format like

`{"verified": true, "id": 42, "date": "bla"}`

and I want to forward this as json with filebeat (6.2.4).
However, because the applications runs inside docker, the log is written to /var/lib/docker/containers//_json.log as:

`{"log":"{\"verified\": true, \"id\": 42, \"date\": \"bla\"}\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-08-10T08:13:53.219511878Z"}`

So now there is a json element `log` with a string value.

When filebeat parses the docker-log file, the content the `log` value is interpreted as a simple string and filebeat produces this output:

`...
  "log": "{\"verified\": true, \"id\": 42, \"date\": \"bla\"}",
  "time": "2018-08-10T09:00:15.038787209Z",
  "stream": "stdout",
...`

Is it possible to parse the field "log" in filebeat so that the filebeat output contains the json elements `verified`, `id` and `date`.

This is my configuration:

`filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      templates:
        - condition:
            contains.docker.container.image: logprod
          config:
            - type: log
              paths:
                - /var/lib/docker/containers/${data.docker.container.id}/*.log
              json.message_key: log
              json.add_error_key: true
              json.keys_under_root: true
output.console:
  enabled: true
  pretty: true`

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: If somebody, stumbles upon this with Graylog Beats input, v2.5.2 can't handle json in a message, 3.x can.